# Multiple Mapkit Views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, maps, mapkit

I am new to Xcode and I am trying to show different locations in the `MapView`. I have been able to set up a `MapView`, set the coordinates and then link it to a `button`, that when pressed displays the `map` with a drop pin.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 54.104456
        var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -6.228926

        var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees  = 0.001
        var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.001

        var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

        var clubLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(clubLocation, theSpan)

        self.MapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

        var clubAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        clubAnnotation.coordinate = clubLocation

        clubAnnotation.title = "Football"

        self.MapView.addAnnotation(clubAnnotation)
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far and it works. I want to have multiple `buttons` that when pressed will show the `map` with the coordinates set for that `location`. I want to show only one `location` for each `button` on the `map`.

This might be easy but I am new to code and any help would be great.

Comment: Do you mean you want several buttons with different point locations and on press event you would like to show that pin on the map, right?

Comment: Yeah. For example in the view controller there is a button which says "Bright football club" and when pressed shows a map view with a pin on the location. I want to be able to have another button in the view controller which says "Kildare Football Club" and when pressed it shows the location on the map with a single pin.

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons from code or from storyboard, here is an example how to add them from code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton
    button.setTitle("football", forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 150, 30)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showFootball:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

and here is example callback:

```
func showFootball(sender: UIButton) {
    var clubAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    clubAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    clubAnnotation.title = "Football"
    let mw = MKMapView()
    mw.removeAnnotations(mw.annotations)
    mw.addAnnotation(clubAnnotation)
}
```

You can add several buttons with different callback using that approach, or you can create an array of locations and assign tags for buttons. Then you can create only one callback and get location based on sender button's tag

Comment: Not too sure how to place this into my code. When I made the Map View I created a view controller and then placed a MapKit View into the view controller. I linked it using the code as above. I then just created a button and pressed ctrl and dragged it to the map. This meant that when I pressed the button in the simulator it brought me to the map. I don't know how to use the code you have given me to achieve what I want. Please help, thanks

Comment: It turns out that you actually have some view controller where you already handle button click, is it so? And you wish add several buttons there to open different maps? Or you wish buttons on a view controller with map?

Comment: Buttons on a view controller which each link to a unique map with a unique pin showing their location

Comment: In that case you can add multiple buttons next to the existing one and add one parameter to your map view controller

Comment: Please check [that tutorial](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/) to learn about passing data between controllers.